# In chef recipe, the resource "script" can do nothing, while "execute" can perform well

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to uninstall some old packages with chef cookbook. So I write a recipe --

```
i331281@vsa9462040:~/eisen/ccloud_av_trendmicro/recipes>cat uninstall_tm.rb
script 'uninstall trendmicro package' do
  interpreter 'bash'
  user 'root'
  code <<-BASH
    rpm -qa|grep "ds_agent\|trend"|xargs -I{} rpm -e {}
  BASH
  only_if 'rpm -q ds_agent'
end
```

But to my surprise -- everytime I ran "chef-client -z -o"recipe[ccloud_av_trendmicro::uninstall_tm]"" -- it's reported that the script is executed well, but always actually doing nothing --

```
vsa10121641:/tmp/cookbooks # chef-client -z -o "recipe[ccloud_av_trendmicro::uninstall_tm]"
[2022-07-27T08:27:32+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
Starting Chef Client, version 12.19.36
[2022-07-27T08:27:33+00:00] WARN: Run List override has been provided.
[2022-07-27T08:27:33+00:00] WARN: Original Run List: []
[2022-07-27T08:27:33+00:00] WARN: Overridden Run List: [recipe[ccloud_av_trendmicro::uninstall_tm]]
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["ccloud_av_trendmicro::uninstall_tm"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - ccloud_av_trendmicro (0.0.10)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: ccloud_av_trendmicro::uninstall_tm
  * script[uninstall trendmicro package] action run
    - execute "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20220727-20794-ewbo7s"
[2022-07-27T08:27:34+00:00] WARN: Skipping final node save because override_runlist was given

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 1/1 resources updated in 02 seconds
vsa10121641:/tmp/cookbooks # rpm -qa|grep "ds_agent\|trend"
trendmicro-updater-1.4268-1.2.SAP.noarch
ds_agent-9.6.2-8140.x86_64
byd-trendmicro-check-1.4859-1.2.SAP.noarch
```

It looks everytime that resource "script" -- won't be executed although it shows so. Then I modify it to another resource type -- "execute" -- then it works --

```
vsa10121641:/tmp/cookbooks # cat ccloud_av_trendmicro/recipes/uninstall_tm.rb
execute 'uninstall trendmicro package' do
  command 'rpm -qa|grep "ds_agent\|trend"|xargs -I{} rpm -e {}'
  only_if 'rpm -q ds_agent'
end
vsa10121641:/tmp/cookbooks # chef-client -z -o "recipe[ccloud_av_trendmicro::uninstall_tm]"
[2022-07-27T08:32:50+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
Starting Chef Client, version 12.19.36
[2022-07-27T08:32:52+00:00] WARN: Run List override has been provided.
[2022-07-27T08:32:52+00:00] WARN: Original Run List: []
[2022-07-27T08:32:52+00:00] WARN: Overridden Run List: [recipe[ccloud_av_trendmicro::uninstall_tm]]
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["ccloud_av_trendmicro::uninstall_tm"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - ccloud_av_trendmicro (0.0.10)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: ccloud_av_trendmicro::uninstall_tm
  * execute[uninstall trendmicro package] action run
    - execute rpm -qa|grep "ds_agent\|trend"|xargs -I{} rpm -e {}
[2022-07-27T08:32:53+00:00] WARN: Skipping final node save because override_runlist was given

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 1/1 resources updated in 02 seconds
vsa10121641:/tmp/cookbooks # rpm -qa|grep "ds_agent\|trend"
```

I don't know why in chef, the "script" can't run while "execute" can. Please have a look --if I made some mistakes on resource type "script"?
Thanks

Updated:
I tested another one using resource "script" to run a "for" loop to touch files in /tmp... this one works fine, but the previous "script" to call rpm to uninstall packages stil failed...
It's too weird...

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `script`/`execute` resources with logic when the [package resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/package/) is meant to do it.

Comment: oh...It's due to our team's habbit -- all use "script"/"execute" to handle these packages' installation and uninstallation. I also don't know why , but have to follow it...